# ajax request SyntaxError: missing ;

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

okay i want to run this via javascript console i installed Jquery via

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

and get SyntaxError: missing ; before statement error

```
function SolveRecaptchaV2(APIKey, googleKey, pageUrl){
        var requestUrl = "http://2captcha.com/in.php?key=" + APIKey + "&method=userrecaptcha&googlekey=" + googleKey + "&pageurl=" + pageUrl;

        $.ajax({url: requestUrl, success: function(result){
            if(result.length < 3){
                return false;
            }else{
                if(result.substring(0, 3) == "OK|"){
                    var captchaID = result.substring(3);

                    for(var i=0; i<24; i++){
                        var ansUrl = "http://2captcha.com/res.php?key=" + APIKey + "&action=get&id=" + captchaID;   

                        $.ajax({url: "ansUrl", success: function(ansresult){
                                if(ansresult.length < 3){
                                    return ansresult;
                                }else{
                                    if(ansresult.substring(0, 3) == "OK|"){
                                        return ansresult;
                                    }else if (ansresult != "CAPCHA_NOT_READY"){
                                        return ansresult;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                         await sleep(5000);
                    }

                }else{
                    return ansresult;   
                }
            }
        },
        fail: function(){
            return "";
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: `await sleep(5000);` - you can only use `await` inside a function declared `async`

Comment: also, `return`ing a value from a `success:` or `fail:` function is meaningless - the value returned isn't available anywhere, so, it's pointless

Comment: clearly you are using this `await sleep(5000)` because you don't know how to deal with asynchronous code

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: and `{url: "ansUrl"` is not what you want either